# flotchart, disable decimal points on graph scale

Tags: javascript, graph, charts, scale, flot

in my flotgraphs none of the items in the dataset contain decimal points but in its auto-scaling routine it sometimes decides to show me intermediary decimal points

I don't want it do to that, is there anyway to have it not do that?

The reason this is important is because there are never decimal values in this data set, so it is unnecessary to imply that there would be or to think that it is a helpful addition to the scale

http://jsfiddle.net/gamm/t3Vqh/2/

```
var dataset = [overdue, open, completed];

var options = {
    series: {
        stack: true,
        bars: {
            show: true
        }
    },
    bars: {
        align: "center",
        horizontal: false,
        barWidth: .8,
        lineWidth: 0
    },
    grid: {
        borderWidth: 0,
        borderColor: null,
        backgroundColor: null,
        labelMargin: 10,
        minBorderMargin: 10
    },
    yaxis: {
        tickColor: "FFFFFF"
    },
    xaxis: {
        tickColor: "FFFFFF",
        ticks: [
            [1, "Public Works"],
            [2, "Sanitation"],
            [3, "Mayor"],
            [4, "L&I"],
            [5, "Police"]
        ]
    },
    legend: {
        position: 'ne',
        show: true
    }
};

$.plot($("#example-section15 #flotcontainer"), dataset, options);
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use the axis [tickDecimals](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#customizing-the-axes) option, like this:

```
yaxis: {
    tickDecimals: 0
}
```